# IE7 float right causes parent element to take up full width

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I am completely baffled by this and don't fully understand IE7's problem. The page in question is [here](http://mpreview.ami.co.nz) and I'm talking about the top grey menu bar. On all other reasonably modern browsers it looks just fine. On IE7 (and possibly IE6 too, but we don't support that) the `div.navArrow` element having `float:right` gets pused all the way to the right, making the parent element `<li>` take up the remaining width of the page.

I'm not sure where to start in fixing this. Any ideas please?

Comment: Try using a min-width for the div.navArrow element as well. Also, for testing, add a width to the parent li and see if that makes a difference. IE7 uses the min-width property. Also, see if adding zoom:1 makes any difference.

Comment: Please post your solution below and then accept your own answer.  That is the proper way to use this site when solving your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually fixed this by applying an special css for IE7 and below. I gave the parent `<li>` a `float:right` style, and `div.navArrow` a `float:none`. That seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Meybe will help you to use any kind. By experience I know that what `position: relative;` don't fix, you can fix it with `zoom: 1;` in IE7. Facebook uses this clearfix:

```
.clearfix{
    zoom: 1;
}
.clearfix::after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

If doesn't matter that the content don't flow out of the container, you can set the container with `overflow: hidden;` and that use to work pretty fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a space before your DOCTYPE and is what is most likely triggering this issue. Also, define a proper DOCTYPE (such as `<!DOCTYPE html>`) and validate your page, its full of errors.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmpreview.ami.co.nz%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0